# Issue in setting up an existing Ruby On Rails Project in local setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, database-schema, migrate

I am setting up an existing 'Ruby On Rails' project to my local system (Having Mac OS X 10.8). I have installed all the required gems but, when i am trying to Load database schema for the project it shows error in terminal 'Could not find table rv_classes'
i am a very beginner in Ruby On Rails.
I have no clues now how to fix it. thanx in advance.

The response from terminal is as following

```
Cynosures-Mac-mini:sunridgerv cynosure$ bundle exec rake db:schema:load
rake aborted!
Could not find table 'rv_classes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:450:in `table_structure'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:333:in `columns'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:95:in `block (2 levels) in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:185:in `with_connection'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:92:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:106:in `yield'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:106:in `default'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:106:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `yield'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `default'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:717:in `columns_hash'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/locking/optimistic.rb:145:in `locking_enabled?'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/relation.rb:111:in `to_a'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:159:in `all'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/base.rb:441:in `all'
/Users/cynosure/Documents/myapp/sunridgerv/app/models/rv_class.rb:7:in `<class:RvClass>'
/Users/cynosure/Documents/myapp/sunridgerv/app/models/rv_class.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in `block in load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:455:in `load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:489:in `load_missing_constant'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:181:in `block in const_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:179:in `const_missing'
/Users/cynosure/Documents/myapp/sunridgerv/app/admin/rv_classes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:164:in `block in load!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:164:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:164:in `load!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin/application.rb:182:in `routes'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin.rb:74:in `routes'
/Users/cynosure/Documents/myapp/sunridgerv/config/routes.rb:32:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:264:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:264:in `eval_block'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:241:in `draw'
/Users/cynosure/Documents/myapp/sunridgerv/config/routes.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `block in load_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:29:in `load_paths'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:13:in `reload!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application.rb:87:in `reload_routes!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:34:in `reload!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:97:in `reload!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:92:in `block in initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `call'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:32:in `execute_if_updated'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:83:in `execute_if_updated'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bundler/gems/active_admin-d7c784a2f1b1/lib/active_admin/reloader.rb:109:in `block in attach!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:404:in `_run_prepare_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/actionpack-3.1.10/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:46:in `prepare!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:41:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
/Users/cynosure/Documents/myapp/sunridgerv/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.1.10/lib/rails/application.rb:203:in `block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

***here is the content of my routes.rb***

```
    require 'preowned_rv_class_constraint'
Sunridgerv::Application.routes.draw do


  devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions", registrations: "users/registrations", passwords: "users/passwords" }
  devise_scope :user do
    get "rvparts/shopping/sign_in", to: "rvparts/shopping/users/sessions#new"
    get "rvparts/shopping/login_as_guest", to: "rvparts/shopping/users/sessions#login_as_guest"
    match "rvparts/shopping/checkout_method", to: "rvparts/shopping/users/sessions#checkout_method", via: [:get, :post]
    post "rvparts/shopping/sign_in", to: "rvparts/shopping/users/sessions#create"
  end

  as :user do
    get 'my_account/profile', to: 'my_account/profiles#edit',   as: 'user_profile'
    put 'my_account/profile', to: 'my_account/profiles#update', as: 'user_profile'
  end

  devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

  namespace :admin_rvparts do
    match "part_images/upload_image", to: "part_images#upload_image", via: [:post, :put]
    match "categories/upload_image", to: "categories#upload_image", via: [:post, :put]
    get "categories/:id/get_subcategories", to: "categories#get_subcategories"
  end

  namespace :my_account do
    resource :address, only: [:show, :create, :update]
    resources :orders, only: [:index, :show]
  end


  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)



  resources :products do
    collection do
      get :list_product
      get :search
      get :get_brands
      get :similar
    end
    member do
      get :add_similar
      get :gallery
    end
  end

  resources :product_images, :only => [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]
  resources :rv_class_brand_images, :only => [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]
  resources :preowned_rv_class_images, :only => [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]
  resources :floorplans, :only => [:new, :create, :update, :destroy]
  resources :compares do
    collection do
      get :delete
    end
  end

  resources :favourites do 
    collection do
      get :delete
    end
  end
  resources :news_letter_users
  resources :rv_requests do
    member do
      get :deactivate
    end
  end
  resource :live_chat
  resources :testimonials
  resources :contacts
  resources :vehicles
  resources :news_letters
  resources :worths
  resources :finance_additionals
  resources :customer_surveys
  resources :rv_request_notifications
  resources :contests

  match "financing" => "finance_additionals#new",:as => :financing
  match "news_letter_delete" =>"news_letter_users#delete",:as => :news_letter_delete
  match "cancel_news_letter" => "news_letter_users#cancel_news_letter",:as => :cancel_news_letter
  match "products/classes/:permalink" => "products#list_by_category", :as => :rv_class
  match "products/brands/:permalink" => "products#list_by_brand", :as => :brand

  #not used
  match "makes/:page_name" => "makes#details", :as => :makes_details 

  # chat routes
  match "live_chat/chat" => "live_chat#chat", :as => :chat
  match "live_chat/publish" => "live_chat#publish_chat", :as => :publish_chat
  match "live_chat/disconnect" => "live_chat#disconnect", :as => :disconnect

  match ":permalink", to: "rv_classes#preowned", as: :preowned_rv_classes, constraints: PreownedRvClassConstraint.new

  match "contest_form" => "contests#new", :as=> :contest_form

  root :to => "content#index"

  get "/parts_home" => redirect("/rvparts/parts_home")
  get "/winegard_satellite_antennas" => redirect("/rvparts/winegard_satellite_antennas")
  get "/sharp_solar_panels" => redirect("/rvparts/sharp_solar_panels")
  get "/gentron_generators" => redirect("/rvparts/gentron_generators")

  namespace :rvparts do
    get "/", to: "content#index", as: :root
    get "/parts_home", to: "content#parts_home"
    get "/customer_surveys", to: "content#customer_surveys"
    get "/winegard_satellite_antennas", to: "content#winegard_satellite_antennas"
    get "/sharp_solar_panels", to: "content#sharp_solar_panels"
    get "/gentron_generators", to: "content#gentron_generators"
    get "/why_SRV", to: "content#why_SRV"

    get "/contact", to: "mails#rvparts_contact", as: :contact_mailer
    post "/contact", to: "mails#send_rvparts_contact", as: :send_contact_mailer

    resources :parts, only: [:index, :show]

    #get "/categories/:category_permalink/subcategories/:id", to: "subcategories#show", as: :subcategory
    #get "/:subcategory_permalink/:id", to: "parts#show", as: :part

    namespace :shopping do
      get "/sign_in", to: "user/sessions#new", as: :sign_in

      resource :cart, only: [:show, :update]
      resource :address, only: [:show, :create, :update]
      resource :shipping_method, only: [:show] do
        collection do
          post :select
        end
      end
      resource :payment, only: [:show, :create] do
        collection do
          post :declined
        end
      end
      resources :order_items, only: [:create, :update, :destroy]
      resources :finishs, only: [:show]
    end

    get ":id", to: "categories#show", as: :category
    get ":category_id/:id", to: "subcategories#show", as: :subcategory
  end

  get ":make/:brand_permalink/:rv_class_permalink", to: "brands#details", as: :brand_details

  match ':action' => 'content'
end
```

after commenting the line  ActiveAdmin.routes(self) i ran again 'bundle exec rake db:schema:load'
then i got the following response...

```
Cynosures-Mac-mini:sunridgerv cynosure$ bundle exec rake db:schema:load
-- create_table("active_admin_comments", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0173s
-- add_index("active_admin_comments", ["author_type", "author_id"], {:name=>"index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"})
   -> 0.0019s
-- add_index("active_admin_comments", ["namespace"], {:name=>"index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"})
   -> 0.0021s
-- add_index("active_admin_comments", ["resource_type", "resource_id"], {:name=>"index_admin_notes_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"})
   -> 0.0025s
-- create_table("addresses", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0036s
-- add_index("addresses", ["country_id"], {:name=>"index_addresses_on_country_id"})
   -> 0.0020s
-- add_index("addresses", ["state_id"], {:name=>"index_addresses_on_state_id"})
   -> 0.0027s
-- create_table("admin_users", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0742s
-- add_index("admin_users", ["email"], {:name=>"index_admin_users_on_email", :unique=>true})
   -> 0.0023s
-- add_index("admin_users", ["reset_password_token"], {:name=>"index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", :unique=>true})
   -> 0.0020s
-- create_table("advertisement_images", {:force=>true})
   -> 0.0027s
-- create_table("blog_posts", {:force=>true})
rake aborted!
SQLite3::SQLException: duplicate column name: ID: CREATE TABLE "blog_posts" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, "post_title" text, "post_date" datetime, "post_content" text, "post_image" varchar(255), "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, "post_name" varchar(255), "ID" integer) 
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `initialize'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `new'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:91:in `prepare'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/database.rb:134:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:270:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:245:in `block in log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:240:in `log'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:270:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_statements.rb:171:in `create_table'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:447:in `block in method_missing'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:422:in `block in say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:422:in `say_with_time'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/migration.rb:442:in `method_missing'
/Users/cynosure/Documents/myapp/sunridgerv/db/schema.rb:76:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/schema.rb:50:in `instance_eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/schema.rb:50:in `define'
/Users/cynosure/Documents/myapp/sunridgerv/db/schema.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `block in load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `block in load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:640:in `new_constants_in'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:223:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.1.10/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:234:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.1.10/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:358:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `eval'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:schema:load
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

***As it says a duplicate column "ID" in 'blog_posts' table ... here is the schema for this table in schema.rb***

```
 create_table "blog_posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.text     "post_title"
    t.datetime "post_date"
    t.text     "post_content"
    t.string   "post_image"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "post_name"
    t.integer  "ID"
  end
```

Comment: Please show your `routes.rb`.

Comment: have you created the database itself, then done a `rake db:migrate`?

Comment: @MaxWilliams it won't work. BTW, for moving existing project to other machine, `rake db:schema:load` is usually faster.

Comment: What do you mean "it won't work"?  Personally i would just take a dump of the live database and push it into a freshly created local db, but migration is the "standard" way to go isn't it?

Comment: @MaxWilliams I mean, he'll get the same error. It won't solve the problem.

Comment: Wish I could help - would love to learn the solution

Comment: @MarekLipka i am adding routes.rb code in the question please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment out this line:

```
ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
```

then run your `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` and uncomment it back.

About your second error, I guess you should remove `t.integer "ID"` line from `blog_posts` in your schema.

Comment: Thanx Mr. @marek Lipka .... something definitely  went better still having an error.

Comment: sorry Mr. @Marek Lipka can you suggest me where i can put the terminal response so that you can see... i guess adding it again in the question will be a bad idea.... (This is my first question in StackOverflow so not very familiar in asking)

Comment: @BrijPatel adding it again in the question would be good idea.

Comment: thnx it worked i did same as you said then i ran 'bundle exec rake:db:migrate' it also executed successfully... after running 'rails server' i found this error on in browser 'NoMethodError in ContentController#index'... what is this?